# list the uniq lines based on ":" delimiter

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to write a script which will find the unique lines(first occurance) based on columns/delimiters. In this case to my understanding delimiter is ":".

## for example:

```
May 14 00:00:01  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748797.780852: ndtpq.c(20544): this is the log  
May 14 00:00:01  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748797.780853: ndtpq.c(20544): this is another log  
May 14 00:00:02  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748798.780852: ndtpq.c(20544): this is another log  
May 14 00:00:03  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748799.780852: ndtpq.c(20544): this is the log  
May 14 00:00:04  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748800.780852: ndtpq.c(20544): this is the log  
May 14 00:00:04  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748800.790852: ndtpq.c(20544): this is the log  
May 14 00:00:05  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748801.790852: ndtpq.c(20544): thisis really different log
```

## desired output:

```
May 14 00:00:01  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748797.780852: ndtpq.c(20544): this is the log  
May 14 00:00:01  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748797.780853: ndtpq.c(20544): this is another log  
May 14 00:00:05  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748801.790852: ndtpq.c(20544): thisis really different log
```

I am able to find the uniq log using the following command but ,I am loosing the timestamp by using this way.

```
cat fileName |awk -F: '{print $7}'
```

Comment: What is the criteria for determining entries that should be grouped? Is it the content of the message? If so, what if the same message is generated later on?

Comment: its the content of the message and it can be ignored if seen later. Only first occurance is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do:

```
awk -F: '!seen[$NF]++' file
May 14 00:00:01  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748797.780852: ndtpq.c(20544): this is the log
May 14 00:00:01  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748797.780853: ndtpq.c(20544): this is another log
May 14 00:00:05  SERVER1 ntp[1006]:  ntpd[Info]: 1430748801.790852: ndtpq.c(20544): thisis really different log
```

It splits the file using `:`, then looks at the last field, and prints only the unique.

Comment: error I got : seen[: Event not found.

Comment: @user2809888 : You are invoking the shell's history substitution. Surround the exclamation point with single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Awk**

```
 awk -F: '!x[$NF]++' infile
```

**GNU Sort** if order doesn't matter

```
 sort -u -t: -k7 infile
```

Comment: Your   `awk` is just the same is I already posted.

Comment: x[: Event not found.

Comment: @user2809888 : You are invoking the shell's history substitution. Surround the exclamation point with single quotes

Comment: thanks, worked for me, I found sort sweeter and simple :)